# Swift: Weak referenced stored & nested blocks / closures

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting

I'm looking to nest a block / closure whilst another process completes off of the main thread like so

```
typealias FirstBlock = (jsonDictionary:NSDictionary?,errorCode:NSString?) -> Void

typealias SecondBlock = (complete:Bool?,errorCode:NSString?,dictionary:NSDictionary?) -> Void
```

- Controller

  ```
      func startPoint {

          SomeNetworkManager.sharedInstance.firstProcess(self.someDictionary) { (complete, errorCode, dictionary) -> Void in

          // I want to get here with a strong reference to these objects in this class only
          print(complete,errorCode,dictionary)
      }
  }
  ```
- SomeNetworkManager

  ```
  func firstProcess(dictionary:NSDictionary?, completion:SecondBlock?) {

  let request = HTTPRequest.init(requestWithPath:"path", httpMethod: .post) { (jsonDictionary, errorCode) -> Void in

      let organisedDictionary:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary() 
      // Some processing of the json into a new dictionary

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

          if errorCode == nil {

              completion!(complete:true,errorCode:nil,dictionary:organisedDictionary)
          }
          else {

              completion!(complete:false,errorCode:errorCode,dictionary:nil)
          }
      }
  }

  request.postDataDictionary = refinementsDictionary as! NSMutableDictionary
  request.request()

  }
  ```
- HTTPRequest

  ```
  var processBlock:FirstBlock?

  init(requestWithPath path:NSString, httpMethod method:HTTPMethod, andProcessBlock block:FirstBlock) {

      super.init()

      self.requestURL = NSURL(string:path as String);
      self.responseData = NSMutableData()
      self.processBlock = block

      switch (method) {
       case .post:
          self.httpMethod = kPost
          break;
       case .put:
          self.httpMethod = kPut
          break;
       default:
          self.httpMethod = kGet
          break;
      }

  }

  // An NSURLConnection goes off, completes, I serialise the json and then...

  func completeWithJSONDictionary(jsonDictionary:NSDictionary) {

      self.processBlock!(jsonDictionary:jsonDictionary,errorCode:nil)
      self.processBlock = nil
  }
  ```

I'm missing something fundamental regarding ARC retain cycles because every time one of these is called I'm getting a memory leak.. I've had a look at
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html
with no joy.. I think `Defining a Capture List` is the right area, but as for storing a block and how to define it I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all likelihood, you're getting retain cycles because the completion block references the HttpRequest (probably via the calling object), references the completion block, something like:

```
class HttpReference {
    let completion : ()->()

    init(completion:()->()) {
        self.completion = completion
    }
}

class Owner {
    var httpReference : HttpReference?

    func someFunction() {
        httpReference = HttpReference() {
            print(self.httpReference)
        }
    }
}
```

There are two ways to break the cycle, either by using an `unowned` reference or a by using a `weak` reference, both are fairly similar, in this case, the norm would be to use an unowned reference to self by changing:

```
func someFunction() {
    httpReference = HttpReference() { [unowned self] in
        print(self.httpReference)
    }
}
```

Now, `self` isn't retained, thus breaking the retain cycle.

Comment: OK, makes sense, but I think that means I'm going to have to rethink my structure from the ground up. Thanks

Comment: Maybe, but I wouldn't think so.  Usually all it requires is thinking through who has references to what and breaking cycles with judicious application of weak.  The usual suspects are delegates, parent/owner links, and hidden links in closures.

Comment: Yeah you're right, after adding [unowned self] to them has really solved the issue. I had quite a few around so it was hard to see progress until I'd fixed the systemic problem. Cheers :)